# Python Tkinter Listing options not showing info

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a very basic question, i.e. by using Python Tkinter window I want to show list box and from that list, I want to show some information which I select. But I am getting some error.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import*
import tkMessageBox
window = Tk()
window.title('ex - 4,listing option')
frame = Frame(window)
listbox = Listbox(frame)
listbox.insert(1, 'Manual')
listbox.insert(2, 'Auto')
listbox.insert(3, 'AI')
def dialog():
    tkMessageBox('selection','your chice:' + \
    listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))
btn = Button(frame, text = 'Choose',command = dialog)
btn.pack(side = RIGHT, padx = 5)
listbox.pack(side = LEFT)
frame.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)
window.mainloop()
```

**The error is**:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Subhro Jyoti\Desktop\python\ex - 4,listing option", line 12, in dialog
    tkMessageBox('selection','your chice:' + listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkMessageBox` is a collection of different types of message boxes, you have to indicate which one you want to use. For example:

```
def dialog():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('selection','your chice:' + 
    listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))
```

Your choices are showinfo, showwarning, showerror, askquestion, askokcancel, askyesno, or askretrycancel